# Making an Initial Snapshot with Git (Gitlab)

Tags: git, gitlab, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to create an baseline image of my system to include all directories below root. I have setup gitlab, a username, and can get a response front he server when trying to clone, but I am unsuccessful.

The other issue I noticed is all directories that I want to clone (everything below the "/" directory is showing as untracked.

Any good web resources to better understand/troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: That seems like an absolutely horrible idea, there are much better backup solutions available.

Comment: Already covered here http://serverfault.com/questions/248625/putting-a-whole-linux-server-under-source-control-git